# Using Yammer API against a non-default Yammer network when using Azure Active Directory (AAD) tokens

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, yammer

I am trying to call the Yammer API using Azure Active Directory (AAD) tokens by following the steps in Microsoft's blog post [Yammer API with AAD tokens Postman Collection](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/yammer-blog/yammer-api-with-aad-tokens-postman-collection/ba-p/857923)

This works fine against the default Yammer network, just as outlined in the blog post above.

However, whenever I try to call the Yammer API using a `feedId` from a different Yammer network which the AD account still has access to, I'm getting HTTP 404 Not Found response.

How would I perform Yammer API requests against a network which is not the default one?

Comment: Please post your token decoded. https://jwt.ms/

Comment: There is no issue with the JWT token, as I can successfully call the API against the default Yammer network. Crucially, the payload includes `{"aud": "https://api.yammer.com",(...)`

The question is about how to successfully call the API against a different Yammer network for which this token is also valid.